Extract ith marker from marker list for usage in pgfplots
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{xstring}

% Define experiment IDs and corresponding markers
\def\expids{1,2}
\def\markers{*,o} % --> CURRENTLY NOT USED

% Define the table data
\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\, col sep=&]{
Experiment & X & Y \\
Exp1       & 1 & 1 \\
Exp1       & 2 & 4 \\
Exp2       & 1 & 2 \\
Exp2       & 2 & 6 \\
}\data

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]

% Loop over experiment IDs and markers
\foreach \id in \expids {
    \addplot+[
        mark=none, % USE HERE markers{id}
        table/x index={1},
        table/y index={2},
        x filter/.code={
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{\coordindex}{Experiment}\of{\data}
                \IfStrEq{\pgfplotsretval}{Exp\id}
                {}{\def\pgfmathresult{}} }] 
table {\data};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

In this example, I am plotting curves of a table and filter rows based on the ID of the first column. Specifically, I define a comma separated list of ids \def\expids{1,2} to plot two curves using \foreach.
I want to define another list \def\markers{*,o} and use here marker * for id 1 and marker o for id 2. How can I do this?

In the documentation section 4.7. MARKERS, LINESTYLES, (BACKGROUND) COLORS AND COLORMAPS

Defining Own Cycle Lists The second choice for cycle lists is to
provide each entry directly as argument to cycle list,

cycle list={
        {blue,mark=*},
        {red,mark=square},
        {dashed,mark=o},
        {loosely dotted,mark=+},
        {brown!60!black,mark=otimes*,
        mark options={fill=brown!40},
        }% <-- don't add a comma here
        },

code
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{xstring}

% Define experiment IDs and corresponding markers
\def\expids{1,2}
\def\markers{*,o} % --> CURRENTLY NOT USED

% Define the table data
\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\, col sep=&]{
Experiment & X & Y \\
Exp1       & 1 & 1 \\
Exp1       & 2 & 4 \\
Exp2       & 1 & 2 \\
Exp2       & 2 & 6 \\
}\data


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    cycle list={
        {blue,mark=*},
        {red,mark=square},
        {dashed,mark=o},
        {loosely dotted,mark=+},
        {brown!60!black,mark=otimes*,
        mark options={fill=brown!40},
        }% <-- don't add a comma here
        },
]

% Loop over experiment IDs and markers
\foreach \id in \expids {
    \addplot+[
        %mark=none, % USE HERE markers{id}
        table/x index={1},
        table/y index={2},
        x filter/.code={
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{\coordindex}{Experiment}\of{\data}
                \IfStrEq{\pgfplotsretval}{Exp\id}
                {}{\def\pgfmathresult{}} }] 
table {\data};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Elegant. In the meantime, I settled with a makeshift solution using array indexing provided by the math engine. But then macro expansion becomes important and you have to enforce pgfplots actually plots in every iteration...
